# Android Activity.onWindowFocusChanged doesn't get called from within TabHost

Tags: android, android-activity, overriding, android-tabhost

I'm struggling with the problem that the .onWindowFocusChanged() doesn't get called in my custom Activity class. My setup:

Two tabs (containing Activity_1 and Activity_2) in a TabHost, where the 2nd tab is selected by default:

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(currentTabIndex);
```

In both Activities, I added the onWindowFocusChanged() override (because I need to preform calculations after the layout is done drawing):

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

The problem: when the 2nd tab is selected by default, and I click the 1st tab, the onWindowFocusChanged() never gets called within Activity_1 (associated with the 1st tab).
Both Activities extend the normal Activity class.

Any clue on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is happening for me (but with 1st tab selected by default). `onWindowFocusChanged` is called in the first tab, but not the second tab. If the second activity is (later) paused and resumed, `onWindowFocusChanged` is called later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need to wait until a specific View is draw and then make the calculations, you could use viewTreeObserver to listen the layout changes and make your calculations there.
Use it like this:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    // remove the listener so it won't get called again if the view layout changes
    mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    // add your calculations here
}}
```

**EDIT:**

*Credit and thanks to Edison for the further details.*

For those who want to support **API < 16**, you can do

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {     
    mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); 
} else { 
    mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
}
```

Comment: This is a good workaround for using AnimationDrawable.start() in a good spot other than onCreate when onWindowFocusChanged is not properly called. Thanks!

Comment: For those who want to adopt for API<16, you can do        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
          mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
          mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }

Comment: @Edison worth mentioning this necessitated @SuppressLint("NewApi") for onGlobalLayout() in ADT

Comment: So if you add a global listener before setContentView, the view is null and will crash. If you set it after, it's already laid out so it doesn't get called. So. Where. Do. You. Add. The. Code. Please. Add. Context. Around. Your. Answers. When. You're. Dealing. With. A. Dynamic. Framework. With. A. Lifecycle.